# Invalid postback or callback argument[ASP.NET]

Tags: asp.net

I have an `asp.net` page with asp dropdown control, dropdown user control, componentArt callback control and submit button.

On selection of any item from asp.net dropdown control, it makes a server side call(like AJAX) and fill-in the dropdown user control.

Now user select item from the user control drop down and click the submit button to postback the form.

On clicking of submit button the below exception throws.

Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using `<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>` in configuration or `<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>` in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.

If the data is valid and expected, use the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation` method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Kindly tell the reason for getting this exception and provide the solution.

Comment: it seems that I do not see any question mark [`?`] in your question

Comment: please post your c# code

Comment: can you please post your Page_Load event